# Exhausted ResultSet

Tags: java, netbeans

I've been searching for this solution but I cant find the answer i want...
   I have multiple ResultSet's that I want to save to variables. It displays an "Exhausted ResultSet" error. That is my code down bellow.

```
    String ime1="select ime from UPORABNIKI_PODATKI where UPORABNIKI_PODATKI.username='"+user1+"'";
    Statement st1=conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs1=st1.executeQuery(ime1);
    rs1.next();
    String ime11=rs1.getString("ime");

    String priimek2="select priimek from UPORABNIKI_PODATKI where UPORABNIKI_PODATKI.username='"+user1+"'";
    Statement st2=conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs2=st2.executeQuery(priimek2);
    rs2.next();
    String priimek22=rs2.getString("priimek");

    String starost3="select starost from UPORABNIKI_PODATKI where UPORABNIKI_PODATKI.username='"+user1+"'";
    Statement st3=conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs3=st3.executeQuery(starost3);
    rs3.next();
    String starost33=rs3.getString("starost");

    String high4="select max(REZULTATI.rezultat) as high from REZULTATI where REZULTATI.username='"+user1+"'";
    Statement st4=conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs4=st4.executeQuery(high4);
    rs4.next();
    String high44=rs4.getString("high");

    String povprecje5="select UPORABNIKI_PODATKI.povprecje from UPORABNIKI_PODATKI where UPORABNIKI_PODATKI.username='"+user1+"'";
    Statement st5=conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs5=st5.executeQuery(povprecje5);
    rs5.next();
    String povprecje55=rs5.getString("povprecje");
```

I would appreciate a if someone took a little time to solve this.
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking the return value of next. If you get no rows, then `Exhausted ResultSet` will occur.
You should do this way:

```
if (rs1.next()){
   String ime11=rs1.getString("ime");
}
```

Comment: You're half right about why OP gets *Exhausted Resultset* exception.